# How do you add/subtract square roots and a non-root?

Tags: radicals

I'm new to square root addition/subtraction because I haven't done it in a long time, so how do you add or subtract a square root and a non-root? For example, whats 2 + sqrt2? Is the process different if I did 2 + 2sqrt2?

*Edit: radical form, if possible, please. I know how to type these into a calculator and get a decimal. Thanks!

Comment: $2+\sqrt{2}$ is often considered to be as simplified as you can get it... of course you could convert $\sqrt{2}$ into a decimal approximation $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.41421\dots$ so $2+\sqrt{2}\approx 2+1.41421\dots\approx 3.41421\dots$.  Mathematicians prefer things to be kept in exact form however, so $2+\sqrt{2}$ should be left as is to retain exactness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2+\sqrt2$ is $2+\sqrt2$. There is no nicer or simpler way to write that number exactly.

(If you're working with decimal approximations, then of course $2+\sqrt2$ is $2+1.4142\ldots = 3.4142\ldots$).